# Expected ; but got 'event'

Tags: solidity

I'm newbie of solidity develop flatform, when I do a example from solidity document at Remix IDE, I have a error with my event and I don't know how to fix it, here my code:

```
contract Coin {
    address public minter;

    mapping (address => uint) public banlances


    event Sent (address from, address to , uint amount);


    constructor() public {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
    function mint(address recevier, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter)
        require(amount < 1e60);
        banlances[recevier] += amount;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Put a ; at the end of the first line.

Also third to last line.

Comment: thank you so much, by the way do you know about error: Data location must be memory for parameter in function, but none was given when I work with type string at solidity

Comment: my code: contract Coursetro {
    string public fName;
    uint public age;
    function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public  {
        fName = _fName;
        age = _age;
    }
    function getInstructor() public view returns (string, uint) {
        return (fName, age);
    }
}

Comment: I pasted that into Remix and it compiled without error.

Comment: but when I put it into remix, this error happen again, I know it's impolite but can I take your contact like telegram or facebook, so I can capture my computer picture and show you explicitly, Sorry about many question and thanks you for your help

Comment: You should post the details as a new question, with code we can copy/paste/edit and a picture if it helps describe the problem.

Comment: if you're using solc 5.x, you should look at this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59651/receiveaprroval-through-tokenrecipient-interface

Comment: I think my question will explain in this post you recommend to visit.Thank you, you so enthusiasm :D