# receiveAprroval through tokenRecipient interface

Tags: erc-20

I received an error by the compiler regarding the following solidity code and I would like to know what's this error and what's the fix?

```
    interface tokenRecipient { function   receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }
```

Error in

```
    TypeError: Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function, but none was given.
    interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }
```

Comment: It gives no error in Remix at least. Where do you get the error?

Comment: In Remix compiler version:0.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some breaking changes in Solidity version 0.5. More details at: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html

One of these breaking changes is:

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters and return variables. For example, change uint[] x = m_x to uint[] storage x = m_x, and function f(uint[][] x) to function f(uint[][] memory x) where memory is the data location and might be replaced by storage or calldata accordingly. Note that external functions require parameters with a data location of calldata.

This explicitly states that if your function is `external` the location type must be `calldata` - but the location is only required for structs, arrays and mappings. As `bytes` is almost the same as `byte[]` it is considered as an array (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#arrays).

If you're wondering what is `calldata`, this is also explained at https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#data-location

> There is also a third data location, calldata, which is a non-modifiable, non-persistent area where function arguments are stored. Function parameters (not return parameters) of external functions are forced to calldata and behave mostly like memory.